# prefix -g not recognized as an internal or external command, this is how it shows when i typ on cmd

Tags: javascript, node.js, windows, windows-7

i have downloaded node js now the next step is that have to type

```
node -v
```

on cmd which is working fine but

```
npm -v
```

is not it shows tht "prefix -g not recog[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VsqCY.png)nized as an internal or external command"
i did everything with enviironment veriable still its not working, anyone has any idea hat i can do? i am using windows 7.[[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UtYaM.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4wHFA.png)

i have pasted the screenshots as well

Comment: Where have you found this old version? In a museum? Current versions are 18 for LTS and 19. Your version has reached end of life two years ago.

Comment: It looks to be working. when you type `npm -v` the text you see is the command of the batch file, but the last line correctly reports npm version 6.14.4. However, jabaa is right about the versions. You should download the lastest versions or you will run into many problems trying to do things using functionality not supperted by the old version you are using

Comment: @DavePile: the OP can't use a later version of node, because they are using Windows 7, which went out of support over three years ago and more recent versions of Node have dropped support for Windows 7. Arguably they should upgrade their OS version too, but that may be beyond their control.

Comment: @LukeWoodward Then they should prefer an even number. LTS versions are longer maintained. v12 was maintained until last year.